# Simple way to "sleep" but consume CPU time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sleep

I am testing a scheduller that has a timeout based on a used CPU time.

To test it, I need some simple alternative that

will be equal to `sleep <timeout is seconds as a float>` that

will loop, i.e. utilize a CPU time and return once the timeout is elapsed.

How to write it simply in a shell?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/443406/how-can-i-produce-high-cpu-load-on-a-linux-server

Comment: @ChenA. Yes, I tried to lookup other answers too, but none of them was simple one liner... See my answer now, I figured out a solution with `timeout` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
timeout 5 sha1sum /dev/zero
```

Advantages:

- it uses `timeout` and `sha1sum` presented in any standard linux
- `sha1sum` can be easily replaced with some multi-threaded command to utilize more than one CPU

Comment: +1, **but** unfortunately, `timeout` is not in fact guaranteed by the POSIX standard. Or maybe you mean it's provided by "common" Linux distros? The word "standard" has a specific meaning. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068 describing the different and not-mutually-compatible implementations of `timeout`, keeping in mind that embedded distros that don't ship GNU coreutils do very much exist.

Comment: That's an amazingly simple answer.  I mean that as a compliment.